# Possible to retrieve steam server list in python?

Tags: python

I wanted to hear whether it was possible to find a way to retrieve steam servers in python?
If so, how could one go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valve has documented the [Master Server Query Protocol](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Master_Server_Query_Protocol) rather well. There is also a Python library called [SourceLib](http://github.com/frostschutz/SourceLib) that provides an interface to the server list.